# Forces at angles being resolved into perpendicular components

Tags: forces

Why is that when a force acts at 30° from the horizontal, for example, that its horizontal and vertical components can be treated as being separate?

Comment: Why do you expect otherwise? Force is a vector which can be decomposed in terms of any basis, not just horizontal and vertical components.

Comment: Yes but why is it possible to do so?

Comment: Arguing in more physical terms, this is the linear superposition principle at work. It is saying that forces orthogonal to each other can be treated independently (because a force can not have any impact into a direction orthogonal to it), which makes things a lot easier.

Comment: I'm sure this has been aksed before, but I'm struggling to find it ...

Comment: Forces are modelled as vectors exactly because you can do so. Otherwise vectors would be useless.

Comment: @JohnRennie Is this what you were looking for?  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18080/some-questions-about-the-logics-of-the-principles-of-independence-of-motion-and

Comment: @Sanya "It is saying that forces **orthogonal** to each other can be treated independently" It isn't necessary that forces are orthogonal. Vector summation is valid for all angles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Experiment shows that forces act that way.

Forces add the same way that vectors add, so vectors make an excellent mathematical representation of a force.   There is a rule for the addition of vectors; two vectors can add to produce a third.  In math, the addition rule is just a definition.  The fact that forces behave the same way is a question of *physics*, not *math*.  The connection between the physics and the math is called, in physics, the *superposition principle*.

Answer (score 1):

Through experimentation, observation, testing, etc., forces have been classified as vectors. A vector is a mathematical conceptual construct which has certain rotation properties. The magnitude of the vector must be invariant under rotation of either the vector or the coordinate system used to describe the vector. Vectors also belong to a class of objects which have linear properties. That ultimately means that the addition of two vectors results in a vector, and the *any* two (or three or four or ...) vectors which add to the same vector as  another sum will yield an identical behavior.  Consequently, we are free, mathematically and physically, to take a single vector and break it down into whatever sum of vectors we want to consider. Usually, this decomposition into a sum of pieces is chosen to give pieces which are parallel to our chosen coordinate system.

Why can we do this? Because the math allows it, and the physics doesn't prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

Force can be visualised as vector.Vector because force acts in a direction and has a magnitude similar to vector property.In 2D space resolving vector into two perpendicular components indicates force acts in x-direction with same magnitude as in y-direction.so in order to find the magnitude in different direction we resolve force into components. 
By just multiplying force vector magnitude with trigonometric ratio of the inclination made with axes.

Answer (score -3):

**Bro**, *A force is a vectorial component. that is it has a direction and magnitude. The magnitude needs to act in the direction available i.e the force acts in the direction available and generally when we do any task(apply force), the object is on the ground thus is is free to move horizontally and vertically because it can't move at an angle inside the ground. the force is split into components in the directions with respect to ground where it can move.*[image]

*hope you deciphered from the image what i mean to say. there is no hard and fast rule that the force is split into horizontal and vertical components. It gently splits into the direction where the force can move. Bro remember Newton's law,,,, Every action has a reaction. the force applied has to neutralize somewhere. So it finds a direction to move on. If I am wrong at any step. please let me know.*   :-)